# Getting Selected name of a dropdown using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have created one dropdown box

```
<select name="select" id="selectId">
<option id="" value="calendar_Second_Calendar_1285942672.xml">Second Calendar</option>
<option id="" value="calendar_First_Calendar_1285932160.xml">First Calendar</option>
</select>
```

I can get the selected drop down box value using

```
document.getElementById("selectId").value
```

How i can get the name where user is seeing i mean (Second Calendar or First Calendar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ujYM6/2/) a go:

```
var domNode = document.getElementById("selectId");
var value = domNode.selectedIndex;
var selected_text = domNode.options[value].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the name by a simple if else statements on the given value.